# Can't install devtools

Tags: r, devtools

I can't install devtools:

```
if (!require("devtools")) install.packages("devtools") 
devtools::install_github("rstudio/httpuv")
```

produces:

> ERROR: dependency 'pkgload' is not available for package 'devtools' *
>   removing 'C:/Users/R/win-library/3.3/devtools'

```
install.packages('pkgload')
```

creates:

> Package which is only available in source form, and may need
>   compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘pkgload’ These will not be installed –

Comment: You're using a relatively old version of R. Install the latest and try again

Answer (score 1):

It can't seem to download some of the packages that `devtools` depends on. Try the following and see if it works-

```
devtools::install_github(repo = "r-lib/devtools",
                         dependencies = TRUE,
                         upgrade = TRUE)
```

If you don't have `devtools` on your system, download `remotes` from `CRAN` and then repeat the exact code as above

```
   remotes::install_github(repo = "r-lib/devtools",
                             dependencies = TRUE,
                             upgrade = TRUE)
```

Comment: Installing devtools from CRAN worked fine. But installing devtools doesn't work. Error: (converted from warning) package ‘BiocInstaller’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)